# How would you describe DSM in simple terms?

Tags: matrix, structure, dependencies

How would you describe DSM in simple terms?

Comment: Why not look it up on Wikipedia?

Comment: Well, the wikipedia article could be simpler.

Comment: I was looking for developers to put it into their own words. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea behind a DSM is that it represents the "dependency" or "uses" relationship in a tabular form.  Parnas defined the "uses" relation between A and B so that when B "uses" A, it means B depends on A's correct operation for its own correct operation.

The uses relation forms a graph in a real system.  The DSM is a matrix representation of that graph, what's called an "[incidence matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix)", where each cell is marked if there is a uses relation between the components.  So if there are *n* components in a DSM *D*, *D<sub>i,j</sub>* = 1 *iff* *j* "uses" *i*.

Comment: Good translation into something that everyone *should* be more familiar with (namely, graph theory) but I do think you meant adjacency matrix, since it's representing a relation from vertices to vertices.

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, a DSM is a different visual way than *boxes and arrows diagram* to represent a graph. The interesting thing, is that, while *boxes and arrows diagrams* are good at showing small graphs with a few dozens of node and not too many connections (sparse graph), DSM are better than *boxes and arrows diagram* at showing larger graph. For that we say that **DSM scales**. The downside is that DSM is not as intuitive as *boxes and arrows diagram* and come with a learning curve.

Compare to *boxes and arrows diagrams*, DSM is especially good to make structural patterns obvious. Concretely, on this blog post [Identify Code Structure Patterns at a Glance](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/08/24/identify-code-structure-patterns-at-a-glance.aspx) it is explained how to use a Dependency Structure Matrix to identify Code Structure Patterns. The screenshots are done with the [Dependency Structure Matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#DependenciesView) of the tool NDepend. Here are a few patterns:

Layered code (code with no cycle, certainly the coolest thing that a DSM can show you at a glance)
[image]

Code with dependency cycles
[image]

High Cohesion / Low-Coupling
[image]

Hungry Caller 
[image]

Popular Callee
[image]

Mutual Coupling
[image]

Data Object
[image]

Comment: Its a good writeup, but I think the key to my question was "simple terms" -- like if you were going to explain DSM to your spouse.